# How do I select the input element?

Tags: html, css

Hello I've been wondering why i can't select the checkbox if I enclose it in a div. But if I remove the div, I can select the checkbox.

How can I select the checkbox enclosed in a div?(I don;t want to lose my styling on that div)

Here's my code

Code that works:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
        <label for="checkbox">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </label>
```

CSS:

```
input:checked ~ .menu-items {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

---

DOES NOT WORK (what can I do here )
HTML:

```
 <div class="event-listener">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <label for="checkbox">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #000000"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.event-listener input:checked ~ .menu-items {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Comment: You're not targeting the checkbox but `.menu-items` using the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). What's `menu-items`?

Answer (score 0):

it's not visible from your first snippet, but if it's work then `.menu-items` must be a following sibling of the `input`.

In the second snippet it's not a sibling anymore, since you nested the `input`. In this case you may use `:has` like so

```
.event-listener:has(input:checked) ~ .menu-items {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

it'supported by [every major browser](https://caniuse.com/css-has) with the exception of Firefox in which the `:has` support [is planned](https://twitter.com/bramus/status/1633417411637510144) for the version `113`

Comment: THANK YOU! IT WORKED!!! Rookie mistake tho, haven't realized that they are not sibling anymore